# Appropriate Spring Batch ItemWriter based on element type

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I've been puzzling over a problem for a few days now and would love to hear your ideas.

I'm working on a Spring Batch application and I need to dynamically select the appropriate ItemWriter. **I have 4 ItemWriters and 8 classes**, each of which must be processed by **one** of these ItemWriters. For example:

- Class Dog -> FileItemWriter
- Class Cat -> DatabaseItemWriter
- Class Bird -> AnotherItemWriter
- Class Raccoon -> FileItemWriter again

  and so on...

At the moment I'm using Classifier and If-else, but it doesn't look good. I would like to get a dynamic version without Hardcode.

Maybe Dependency Injection or reflection can accomplish this?

**Update**

I tried something like this:

```
public ItemWriter classify(final Animal animal){
if(animal.getName().eqials("Dog"){
    return FileItemWriter();
}else if(animal.getName().eqials("Cat") {
    return DatabaseItemWriter();
}
```

}

Animal is a superclass of all other classes. We got Animal object from Processor.

Comment: Why do you need an "if-else"? The idea of the classifier is that you map types to corresponding writers and the classifier does the type matching. Please share your code to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: @FadhelMahmoudBenHassine I reworked the problem and inserted a code example. I needed "if-else" this because I didn't know how else I could dynamically classify Writer to classes. The Animal class contains a specific name, based on which the appropriate Writer should be chosen. Maybe I got something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added an answer with more details and a code example. You will see that by using the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`, you only need to map item types to the corresponding writers, and Spring Batch will do the type matching (which shows what I mean by you don't need multiple "if-else" statements). HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the classification manually in the `classify` method which returns a regular item writer. Spring Batch provides the [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) for that very use case. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java).

The example above uses a `PatternMatchingClassifier`, but for your use case, the `org.springframework.classify.SubclassClassifier` should be the way to go (since you said `Animal is a superclass of all other classes`).